# Accessing an inner class´ method from another inner class

Tags: java, methods, inner-classes

I try to access an inner class method from another inner class. Both inner classes are declared in the same outer class:

```
class OuterFoo{

    class innerFoo1{

        public void methodFoo1(){
            System.out.println(" Hello, i am in the inner foo 1");
        }
    }

    class innerFoo2{

        public void methodFoo2(){
           System.out.println(" Hello, i am in the inner foo 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to access `methodFoo1` from `methodFoo2`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the same way as you access an instance method on any class: you need a reference to an instance of that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a reference to an instance of the other inner class. Like this:

```
public class OuterFoo {
    private class InnerFoo1 {
        private void helloFoo1 () {
            System.out.println("foo1");

            InnerFoo2 foo2 = new InnerFoo2();
            foo2.helloFoo2();
        }
    }
    private class InnerFoo2 {
        private void helloFoo2 () {
            System.out.println("foo2");

            InnerFoo1 foo1 = new InnerFoo1();
            foo1.helloFoo1();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your inner classes are instanciated into the `OuterFoo`

You can do it this way :

```
class OuterFoo{
    final innerFoo1 if1 = new innerFoo1();
    final innerFoo1 if2 = new innerFoo2();

    class innerFoo1{
        public void methodFoo1(){
            System.out.println(" Hello, i am in the inner foo 1");
            if2.methodFoo2();
        }
    }

    class innerFoo2{
        public void methodFoo2(){
            System.out.println(" Hello, i am in the inner foo 2");
            if1.methodFoo1();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want your real program should do (if you don't need to instantiate the class InnerFoo and only need a call to a static method), you may also make the class `innerFoo2` and the method `methodFoo2` static.

```
public class OuterFoo{
class innerFoo1{
    public void methodFoo1(){
        System.out.println(" Hello, i am in the inner foo 1");
        OuterFoo.innerFoo2.methodFoo2();
    }
}
static class innerFoo2{
    public static void methodFoo2(){
        System.out.println(" Hello, i am in the inner foo 2");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public class OuterFoo{

    class innerFoo1{

        public void methodFoo1(){
            System.out.println(" Hello, i am in the inner foo 1");
        }
    }

    class innerFoo2{

        public void methodFoo2(){
            System.out.println(" Hello, i am in the inner foo 2");
        }
    }

    void displayInnerFoo1(){
        innerFoo1 object1= new innerFoo1();
        object1.methodFoo1();

    }

    void displayInnerFoo2(){
        innerFoo2 object2= new innerFoo2();
        object2.methodFoo2();

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        OuterFoo objectParent= new OuterFoo();
        objectParent.displayInnerFoo1();
        objectParent.displayInnerFoo2();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the Object of inner class then simply use the dot operator to access it.

```
ClassName obj = new ClassName();
obj.MethodName();
```